# Cancel button not work on edit article in joomla admin 3.4.8

Tags: joomla3.0

can you please help me
if i edit any article in joomla admin panel cancel button is not working in french language but in english it's working fine.
When i click on cancel button and check error through firebug it shows 
TypeError: n is null
...){n||(n=t.getElementById("adminForm")),e&&(n.task.value=e),n.noValidate=!r;var i...

on core.js file

Please guide me how to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the form, you are probably missing the id 'adminForm' on it.